# Boggle variations?

Tags: variants, boggle

This summer we have company staying with us, and they greatly enjoy playing Boggle. I'm looking to spice things up a bit, though - any ideas for Boggle variations that we can try? There will be two to four of us playing at any time.

Answer (score 6):

A few Boggle variants I've heard of:

- Scrabble-style:  Lose the timer - take turns making words, end game when (n) words made (try about 20 to begin with).  You cannot repeat a word already made.
- Collapsing Boggle:  Use a shorter timer.  After it runs out, remove 1 die at random and keep going.  Remove another die and have a third (and final) run through.
- Selective Boggle:  After the dice are placed, each player may rotate one die to a different side.  (For a milder version, have one player rotate one die, changing players each round.)
- Generous Boggle: Allow each die to be used multiple times in one word.
- Scatter Boggle: Only try this with a large size 5x5 Boggle set.  Instead of being adjacent, each die in the word must NOT be adjacent horizontally or vertically.  (Don't count diagonals with this variant; there won't be enough options.)

  I've just invented one more while typing, so this is *completely* untested, and may not even make sense:
- Apples to Boggles.  Get an Apples to Apples set and play it, except that instead of picking a noun from your hand to match the topic for the round, you have to pick a word from the Boggle board to match, and convince people it's the best candidate as usual.  First person to call a word gets it as her "apple" for the round.  (Definitely use the "generous" rule above for this one.)

Answer (score 0):

5 letter Boggle. Minimum word length is 5 letters. You can try this with 6 or 7 letters too.

Answer (score 0):

Boggle Quiz: a description or question is posed to all participants. A boggle board is randomly generated containing the answer and distributed to all participants. The first person to find the correct answer (either fitting the description or answering the question) on the boggle board wins the round.